# Updating local state through React Bootstrap DropdownButton and dropdown items rendered from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I am building an application that gets a list of job descriptions from backend and takes user input to select one of them along with several parameters in order to make a second backend request. Since there will be a few more components involved, I have decided to use Redux for managing global state, and that appears to cause complications in my code.

My DropdownButton component uses handleJobSelect to modify local state and thereby show current selectedJobValue as the value of a FormControl component, and all is apparently well and good if my items are rendered directly (e.g. "Good item" in the code below). If I use a fetched list to map my items, however, selecting one of them will somehow cause the entire website to reload, losing all state changes and resetting both the selectedJobValue and a FormControl value property.

```
    class Settings extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          descriptions: [],
          selectedJobValue: 'None'
        };

        this.handleJobSelect = this.handleJobSelect.bind(this);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/1.0/descriptions');
      }

      handleJobSelect = evt => {
        const someVal = evt;
        console.log(someVal);
        console.log(this.state);
        this.setState({ selectedJobValue: someVal });
        console.log(this.state);
      };

      render() {
        const { selectedJobValue } = this.state;

        return (
           <InputGroup classname="mb-3">
               <DropdownButton
                  as={InputGroup.Prepend}
                  variant="outline-primary"
                  title="Description"
                  id="input-group-dropdown-1"
                  onSelect={this.handleJobSelect}
                >
                  {this.props.items.map(item => (
                    <Dropdown.Item href={item} key={item} eventkey={item}>
                      {item.toString()}
                    </Dropdown.Item>
                  ))}
                <Dropdown.Item href="#">Good item</Dropdown.Item>
                </DropdownButton>
                <FormControl
                  placeholder="Placeholder job description"
                  aria-label="Job description"
                  aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                  value={selectedJobValue}
                  readOnly="True"
                />
             <InputGroup.Append>
                  <Button variant="outline-primary">Submit</Button>
             </InputGroup.Append>
          </InputGroup>

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    items: state.items,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchData: url => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Settings);
```

I suspect that my attempt to use both local and global state is complicit in this issue, but this seems impossible to avoid given my plans for the application. Is there a way to resolve the problem without abandoning Redux?

After going through my code a few more times, I think that the problem is in my use of `href` and `handleJobSelect()` function. Since my description items represent relative file paths with slashes, they are read as valid hrefs that can call the page by themselves, thereby ruining everything. Is it possible to extract through my `handleJobSelect()` function different properties of the target dropdown item, for example, its text (that is, `{item}`)?

Comment: Does `href={item}` actually call the page again ? If not, your `handleJobSelect` calls `setState` which will trigger the entire `render()` again. Instead you can think of splitting the render into two components.

Comment: Don't think ```href``` calls the page, at least not with that "good" item I've added for testing purposes. In case of the rendered items, ```href``` might be a little sketchy, since it includes a filepath with slashes, and those might get interpreted as page calls.


I already did the two-component version (indeed, placing all dropdown items along with data fetching into their own separate component was the original plan), and my current setup was an attempt to simplify it for clarity. Page re-rendering was still there even with two components.